# Service worker / Safari / fetch event fires before the message event

Tags: javascript, jquery, service-worker

I'm new to service workers and I have the following scenario:

Here is a chunk from my script.js:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                var msg = {
                    'form_data': params
                }

                navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage(msg);
        }
}

$.post(url, params, function (data) {        
}).done(function(data) {
        console.log('succ');
}).fail(function() {
        console.log('fail');
});
```

Here is a chunk from my service-worker.js:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
    const reqClone = e.request.clone();

    if (reqClone.method === 'POST') {
        e.respondWith(fetch(reqClone).catch(function(error) {
            savePostRequests(reqClone.url, form_data)
            //Function to add requests to IndexedDB
        }))
    }
});

self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    if (e.data.hasOwnProperty('form_data')) {
            form_data = e.data.form_data;
    }
});
```

While in Chrome the message event gets fired before the fetch event, meaning I'm getting my form_data in the fetch, in Safari the message event gets fired after the fetch event, so I'm not getting the form_data.

I need the POST call parameters in the fetch event to store them in the IndexedDB when I'm offline.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a different way to handle this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am a little confused from your code - are you trying to send a message to your service worker after you're done fetching? Where is `params` in your code and how does it get populated?

Comment: @goto1 my end goal is to add into an IndexedDB, failed POST requests (offline) with their parameters. params gets populated (it's just a chunk from my code), I didn't want to add irrelevant stuff to my question (I can add if you really think it's necessary).

Comment: So why not just inspect all `POST` requests through `SW`, catch the error, grab the `body` of the request, which would be your params, and then use that to save it in `IndexedDB`?

Comment: @goto1 how do I grab the body of the request? That was my initial problem.

Comment: I have an example that grabs `params` of a `POST` request inside of the `ServiceWorker` when a `fetch` request gets triggered. They both work the same way in `Chrome` and `Safari` - is that what you want?

Comment: @goto1 that should help. Thank you.

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this example both in `Chrome` and `Safari` but I am not relying on the `postMessage` method to send the `form_data` parameters. Instead, I am relying on the `ServiceWorker`'s ability to listen for `fetch` events and grab request parameters inside of the handler.

```js
self.addEventListener(`fetch`, event => {
  const requestClone = event.request.clone()

  event.respondWith(
    (async function() {
      const params = await requestClone.text().catch(err => err)

      if (params instanceof Error) {
        // this is a simple check, but handle error appropriately
      }

      if (event.request.method === `POST`) {
        console.log(`POST request with params: ${params}`)
        // do work here
      }
      return fetch(event.request)
    })()
  )
})
```

Note that you have to create a `clone` for the `event.request` to be able to call the `text()` method on it because the "request is a stream and can only be consumed once," so you'd run into issues if you tried to grab the request's `params` and then use it for something else.

Also, you could use any of the following methods to retrieve the body from a request, so use whatever is appropriate:

- `event.request.arrayBuffer()`
- `event.request.blob()`
- `event.request.json()`
- `event.request.text()`
- `event.request.formData()`

Anyway, assuming the above code snippet is included in your `ServiceWorker` file, the following example behaves the same in both browsers:

```js
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({ title: "foo", body: "bar", userId: 1 }),
  headers: { "Content-Type": `application/json` }
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(`fetch response`, json))
  .catch(error => console.error(`fetch error`, error));

// console logs
//  >> POST request with {"title":"foo","body":"bar","userId":1} (worker.js)
//  >> fetch response {title: "foo", body: "bar", userId: 1, id: 101} (index.js)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the post request in service worker, and store it to cache there if it fails. The code bellow should give you some inspiration on how to do it.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {

  if (event.request.clone().method === 'POST') {
    event.respondWith(fetch(event.request.clone(), {method:'POST'})
         .catch(function(error) { // cache only if it fails(offline)

           let url = event.request.clone().url;
           // adjust the response to your needs
           let fakeResponse = new Response(JSON.stringify({status: 'success', success:true})); 

           saveRequest(url, form_data); // custom function to save the request to cache

           return fakeResponse.clone();
         })

  } else {
     // handle GET requests here  
  }
```

To get form_data, I've used this code:

```
// service worker
// global variable
var form_data;
self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    if (event.data.hasOwnProperty('form_data')) {
        form_data = event.data.form_data;
    }
});
```

And I had to add message to every post request I want to cache

```
// plain javascript
// in ajax

// normal form data used when user is online
var data = new FormData();
data.append('photo', image);
data.append('description', description);

// adjusting form data for service worker message
var object = {};
data.forEach((value, key) => {object[key] = value});
var json = JSON.stringify(object);
var msg = {
    form_data: object,
}

// send form data to Service worker through post messages, works offline
swRegistration.active.postMessage(msg);

// submit the request normally.... (online only)
$.ajax({
        url: ajax_url,
        ...
```

This solution is far from elegant, but it worked for me

Comment: It doesn't look much different from my code. Did you try running it on Safari?